# Maven profiles confusion; confusion about user-based authentication to internal repo

Tags: maven, continuous-integration, bamboo

Consider this scenario. I have a small enterprise project dev environment. We use archiva as our artifact repo.

In-general, I would like to have PROJECT-SPECIFIC profiles set up, namely because tests will differ on a per-project basis.

However, the one thing I would LIKE to have constant, is a profile in my settings.xml file, which is active by default, used for development. Do I need to have my team members manually edit that file and place their ARCHIVA credentials in there (ldap system), so that they can access the internal repo?

Should I just not put a password on it? My other alternative is using a master password to encrypt a "shared" password, so nobody could see it, yet they would all have generic "read-only" access to the internal repo for snapshot dependencies and stuff. However, then they would also need the security-settings.xml file which contained the encrypted master password, and doesn't that defeat the purpose of that system?

finally: can multiple profiles be active at the same time, or is that unnecessary? For example, if I have the dev profile active by default (which contains the artifact repo settings, encrypted svn credentials for releases), and then I specify different profiles in certain POM files, am I only to pick ONE profile? Let's say I want to use Bamboo for CI, and there are some "test" profiles which use the surefire plugin and whatnot. Will these profiles co-exist with the activeByDefault DEV profile that exists in settings.xml, or can only one profile be activated at one time? All CI needs is the SCM information, so technically it shouldn't need access to the internal archiva repo, so I suppose that if I was using a test profile (automatically using CI), it wouldn't need anything from the  profile.

I'm confused. I'm so close to having a fully maven-managed build environment, just trying to iron out those few kinks. Thank you.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> However, the one thing I would LIKE to have constant, is a profile in
>   my settings.xml file, which is active by default, used for
>   development. Do I need to have my team members manually edit that file
>   and place their ARCHIVA credentials in there (ldap system), so that
>   they can access the internal repo?

Yes, they would have to edit that file on a pr user basis. From the doc:

*The passphrase and password elements may be externalized in the future, but for now they must be set plain-text in the settings.xml file.*

> Should I just not put a password on it? My other alternative is using
>   a master password to encrypt a "shared" password, so nobody could see
>   it, yet they would all have generic "read-only" access to the internal
>   repo for snapshot dependencies and stuff. However, then they would
>   also need the security-settings.xml file which contained the encrypted
>   master password, and doesn't that defeat the purpose of that system?

Why not add users public key to Archiva, and authenticate that way?

```
<servers>
    <server>
      <id>server001</id>
      <username>my_login</username>
      <privateKey>${user.home}/.ssh/id_dsa</privateKey>
      <passphrase>some_passphrase</passphrase>
      ...
    </server>
  </servers>
```

> finally: can multiple profiles be active at the same time, or is that
>   unnecessary?

Yes, multiple profiles can be active. You can use **mvn help:active-profiles** to list active profiles.

Comment: Dude thanks a ton. Was baffled by all of that but now I finally have what I need to get the last bit set up. CI isn't for a few months, but I just wanted to make sure my environment was "friendly" towards it when I start with it. Right now, it's just svn, archiva, maven etc. Thanks again.

Comment: What do you mean "CI isn't for a few months"? It should be one of the first things you set up ;) Using ie. Jenkins, it's actually very easy to set up locally in the mean time. Anyway, glad I could help out!

Comment: As soon as I have the cash, it will be done. It requires a third box for us, and we don't even have any DAO's yet, so testing won't be too brutal for a bit. Thanks again